# Get String reference from file in resource

Tags: c#, audio, console, wav

i've a function in my c# program (console program) that when invoked i need to pass 1 argument, that argument is a string containing a path for a sound file e.g "C:\users\Danielix\sound.wav" and my function will async. play the file, now i've included that file directly into the resources file; i need to retrieve a string thats like the previous secified; with this i can play a sound file async. and the users dont need to download the sound file but only the exe. how can i achieve this?

Comment: If the file is included as a resource I don't understand why you need a path to it, just read the Data from the resource and play it.

Comment: oh, because my function only want a string type var that contains file path and that is a problem for me, but in a previous program made in c++ i got this reading across internet, but it isnt the same for c#...this is frustrating...

Comment: Yep thats a problem. I take it you can't rewrite the function. If this is correct your function is going to load a file whether you like it or not. Try overloading the function so you don't need a File Path and load the sound from the Resource. Maybe you need to start from scratch on this one.

Comment: umm i ready search about another function to play async sound file but after changing the function i wanna try everything because as ready sayd in my previous c++ program i did it and seems to be impossible to not do it in c# in at least the same way, if you want i can post alil bit of code

Comment: Code would be good but I really think your best option is going to be overloading the function for each method of playing the sound file you wish to use. Note: overload then function don't override it,

Comment: The function is a win32api function called PlaySound how can i do it?

Comment: Your question is too broad, because these days, there are a lot of different things that the word "resource" describes. If you are talking about a regular Windows executable file resource, then you can use the `SND_RESOURCE` flag for the `PlaySound()` function. Another alternative is to read the resource (from wherever you want) into memory and then use the `SND_MEMORY` flag for `PlaySound()`. See [Playing WAVE Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743679(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yes its to load a wav file from resource file of an exe, i tried to add snd_memory or snd_rersource but the problem is how to get the first parameter as a string of the sound; in my previous c++ program i used `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_SOUND)` but i cannot find an analog function like that

Comment: **SOLVED** i decided to migrate onto System.Media functions

Comment: You should be able to do this with `PlaySound`. You have to pass the resource name and include the `SND_RESOURCE` flag to tell the function that it needs to load the sound from a resource. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx is the reference, and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743679(v=vs.85).aspx gives an example in C, which you should be able to convert to C# easily enough. Just have to write the wrapper for `PlaySound`.